# Can I go to bigger RAM?

Tags: memory

I have the Lenovo 10117 Motherboard, and currently it has 2x4gb Ram modules installed. Although I would like to upgrade it to 2x8gb, the only problem being I don't know if this motherboard will support this big. Will it? I was searching for information on it and I could not find any so if you could find any please tell me. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a Lenovo H535?

Comment: Yes That's the one!

Comment: I don't think that would be possible depending on information from this site: http://browser.primatelabs.com/geekbench3/333245

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade to 2x8GB. If you want guaranteed compatibility, Crucial's CT4883750 or Data Memory Systems DM50669 should work. If you don't insist on guaranteed compatibility, get two of pretty much any standard 1.5V DDR3-1600 8GB sticks, preferably CL11 or less.